# Java - Upload file with different name

Tags: java, file

When user select the file it will be stored in the folder(path already set in ProjectConfig file) with different name entered by the User during uploading.
Here is the code in my Servlet,

```
new ProjectConfig(); // For setting path for storing image 
    String dealerGalleryPath = ProjectConfig.get("dealergallery");
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    int locationid=2;
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    String fileName = "";
    try
    {
        java.io.File fnew = null;
        //System.out.println(getServletContext().getRealPath("/images"));

        List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

        Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

        while ( i.hasNext () ) 
        {
            FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
            if ( !fi.isFormField () )   
            {
                // Get the uploaded file parameters
                String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
                //System.out.println("Field Name is.."+fieldName);
                fileName = fi.getName();
                if(fi.getName() != null && fi.getName().trim().length() != 0)
                {
                //System.out.println("File Name is.."+fileName);

                String realWebPath = dealerGalleryPath+locationid+"/"+fi.getName();

                fnew = new java.io.File(realWebPath); // **What to do here to change name of file??**
                fi.write(fnew);
                System.out.println("Success");
                //commonutil.setProductimage(fi.getName());
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("fileName::"+fileName);
        request.setAttribute("ImageName", fileName);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/ImageTesting.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I had a go-through over Questions in this site.. but din't find relevant answer. Thank you in advance

Comment: ...but what is the question?

Comment: uploading file with different name @kryger

Answer (score 0):

Next code works fine in my website :

```
filePath = "upload/"; // DIRECTORY IN THE ROOT OF YOUR WEBSITE.
fileName = fi.getName(); // ORIGINAL FILENAME (YOU DONT WANT IT).
file = new File( filePath + "newname" ); // NEW FILE WITH NEW NAME.
try { fi.write( file ); } // WRITES ORIGINAL FILE INTO NEW FILE.
catch ( Exception ew ) { /* HANDLE ERROR HERE */ }
```

Your question is : // **What to do here to change name of file??**
Well, you don't change anything there, but two lines above in your code just change the "fi.getName()" for the new name you want.